# Handling “Accept All” (cookies) popup - Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a soccer stats website, but in order to access the site, I need to "Accept All" cookies. This only occurs when I use a bot, not when I access the website manually.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com')
    
# click through annoying pop-up
popup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@title,'ACCEPT ALL')]")
popup.click()
```

I think(?) my I've coded the locator portion correctly. Seem to be having trouble navigating the popup. Basic structure below:

```
<button tabindex="0" title="ACCEPT ALL" aria-label="ACCEPT ALL" class="message-component message-button no-children" path="[0,1,1,0]" style="padding: 10px 15px; margin: 5px 10px; border-width: 2px; border-color: rgb(92, 166, 255); border-radius: 4px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; width: 225px; background: rgb(0, 25, 63);">ACCEPT ALL </button>
```

Googling seems to indicate I might need to switch frame? Any help appreciated! Browser snapshot below...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cookie window was located inside a different frame, navigated to that using:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="sp_message_iframe_382445"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@title,'ACCEPT ALL')]"))).click()
```